# How do I automate testing and comparison of the performance of models with different layer depths, layer types, and unit counts?

Tags: nlp, tensorflow, hyperparameter-tuning, model-selection

I am testing the effects of different layer counts/depths, unit counts, and layer types for natural language processing. I made a Kaggle notebook where I manually create different layers and then train them on the same input. This is the [full notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/joachimrives/effects-of-layer-count-and-unit-count). This is the code snippet for building the models:

```py
def generate_model(
    model_optimizer,
    embedding_dimension=32,
    layer_count=1,
    unit_count=1,
    activation_function='selu',
    kernel_initializer_function='glorot_normal',
):
    input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(sequence_max_len,))
    output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
        input_dim=vocabulary_size,
#         input_length=sequence_max_len,
        output_dim=embedding_dimension,
        mask_zero=True,
    )(input_layer)
    
    output_layer = make_layer_block(
        output_layer,
        layer_count,
        unit_count,
        activation_function,
        kernel_initializer_function
    )
    output_layer = tf.keras.layers.GRU(
        units=unit_count,
        activation='selu',
        kernel_initializer='glorot_normal',
        return_sequences=False
    )(output_layer)
    
    output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(output_layer)
    output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation='selu')(output_layer)
    output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16, activation='selu')(output_layer)
    output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(output_layer)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
    model.compile(
        optimizer=model_optimizer,
        loss='binary_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )
    print(model.summary())
    
    return model
```

This code builds several different models and stores their history.

```py
# Python RNG
import random
# TF RNG
from tensorflow.python.framework import random_seed

layer_counts = [1, 3, 6, 9, 12]
unit_counts = [4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
model_performances = dict()


for layer_count in layer_counts:
    for layer_units_count in unit_counts:
        random_seed.set_seed(2)
        np.random.seed(2)
        optimizer_adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.005)
        
        model = generate_model(
            optimizer_adam,
            32,
            layer_count,
            layer_units_count
        )
        
        model_history = model.fit(
            tokenized_train_text,
            train_split_df['target'].to_numpy(),
            validation_data=(
                tokenized_crossval_text,
                crossval_split_df['target'].to_numpy()
            ),
            epochs=30,
            callbacks=[
                tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
                    monitor='val_accuracy',
                    min_delta=0.01,
                    patience=3,
                    verbose=1,
                    mode='auto',
                    baseline=None,
                    restore_best_weights=True,
                    start_from_epoch=0
                )
            ]
        )
        
        name = f"layer_{layer_count}+unit_{layer_units_count}"
        model_performances[name] = model_history
```

The problem is I have to go through the history dictionary to check the model performances. I also need to specify the layer type. It would also require a big change to make different combinations of layers. That isn't possible with the code I have. Is there any way to automate building models with different layer types, layer unit counts, and layer counts or depths? I am open to using TensorFlow, Weights and Biases, and MLFlow to compare model performance. If you have suggestions other than those, please include code snippets or links to examples I can try now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can approach this with WandB: MLFlow can be implemented alternatively without significant effort.

First, we will define the layer combinations that we want to test. This can be abstracted further, using a .toml file, for example, to pass layer combinations into the program for testing. This code is a baseline- you will want to tailor it to your use cases.

```
import itertools

# Define layer combinations
lstm_layers_combinations = [(64,), (128, 64), (256, 128, 64)]
lstm_dropout_layers_combinations = [(0.2,), (0.2, 0.3), (0.2, 0.3, 0.4)]
hidden_fc_layers = [(32,), (64, 32), (128, 64, 32)]
hidden_dropout_layers = [(0.2,), (0.2, 0.3), (0.2, 0.3, 0.4)]
conv1d_filters = [(32,), (64, 32), (128, 64, 32)]
conv1d_kernel_sizes = [(3,), (5, 3), (7, 5, 3)]
conv1d_dropouts = [(0.2,), (0.2, 0.3), (0.2, 0.3, 0.4)]

# Generate combinations
layer_combinations = itertools.product(
    lstm_layers_combinations,
    lstm_dropout_layers_combinations,
    hidden_fc_layers,
    hidden_dropout_layers,
    conv1d_filters,
    conv1d_kernel_sizes,
    conv1d_dropouts
)
```

Next, we will build the model configurations.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Conv1D

def build_model(conv1d_filters=None, conv1d_kernel_sizes=None, conv1d_dropouts=None,
                lstm_layers=None, lstm_dropout_layers=None,
                hidden_fc_layers=None, hidden_fc_dropout=None,
                lstm_input_shape=None, fc_activation='relu', fc_final_activation='sigmoid'):
    inputs = Input(shape=lstm_input_shape)
    x = inputs

    # Conv1D layers
    if conv1d_filters:
        for i, num_filters in enumerate(conv1d_filters):
            kernel_size = conv1d_kernel_sizes[i]
            dropout = conv1d_dropouts[i]
            x = Conv1D(filters=num_filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
            x = Dropout(dropout)(x)

    # LSTM layers
    if lstm_layers:
        for i, num_lstm in enumerate(lstm_layers):
            return_seq = True if i < len(lstm_layers) - 1 else False
            x = LSTM(units=num_lstm, return_sequences=return_seq)(x)
            if lstm_dropout_layers:
                x = Dropout(lstm_dropout_layers[i])(x)

    # Flatten the output if necessary
    if len(x.shape) > 2:
        x = Flatten()(x)

    # Fully connected layers
    if hidden_fc_layers:
        for i, num_hidden in enumerate(hidden_fc_layers):
            x = Dense(units=num_hidden, activation=fc_activation)(x)
            if hidden_fc_dropout:
                x = Dropout(hidden_fc_dropout[i])(x)

    # Final Dense layer for predictions
    outputs = Dense(1, activation=fc_final_activation)(x)

    # Create model
    model = Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model
```

Finally, we will train the models and log the results to WandB.

```
import wandb
from wandb.keras import WandbCallback

# Initialize WandB
wandb.init(project='your-project-name', entity='your-entity')

# Iterate over layer combinations
for layer_combination in layer_combinations:
    conv1d_filters, conv1d_kernel_sizes, conv1d_dropouts, lstm_layers, lstm_dropout_layers, hidden_fc_layers, hidden_fc_dropout = layer_combination
# Build model
model = build_model(
    conv1d_filters=conv1d_filters,
    conv1d_kernel_sizes=conv1d_kernel_sizes,
    conv1d_dropouts=conv1d_dropouts,
    lstm_layers=lstm_layers,
    lstm_dropout_layers=lstm_dropout_layers,
    hidden_fc_layers=hidden_fc_layers,
    hidden_fc_dropout=hidden_fc_dropout,
    lstm_input_shape=input_shape
)

# Compile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Configure WandB for this model
wandb.config.update({
    'conv1d_filters': conv1d_filters,
    'conv1d_kernel_sizes': conv1d_kernel_sizes,
    'conv1d_dropouts': conv1d_dropouts,
    'lstm_layers': lstm_layers,
    'lstm_dropout_layers': lstm_dropout_layers,
    'hidden_fc_layers': hidden_fc_layers,
    'hidden_fc_dropout': hidden_fc_dropout,
})

# Train model and log metrics to WandB
model.fit(
    train_data,
    validation_data=val_data,
    epochs=30,
    callbacks=[WandbCallback()]
)

# Save model to WandB
wandb.keras.save_model(model, 'model.h5')
```

You can enhance the WandB logging by tracking more parameters, such as batch size, learning rate, optimizer, and many other elements. I also run a comprehensive test and validation pipeline for each model that does not hit one of my callbacks which results in an exception. (Everything is in a try-except loop, for example) These results are logged locally and to WandB as well.

Here is an example of one of the plots I generate and log to WandB as an artifact.

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I ran into an error that said `wandb.errors.CommError: Run initialization has timed out after 90.0 sec. 
Please refer to the documentation for additional information: https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/track/tracking-faq#initstarterror-error-communicating-with-wandb-process-`

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
NameError: name 'traceback' is not defined

Comment: Could the error above be caused by running this code in a Kaggle notebook? I also assumed the "entity" is the username in the URL of my browser when I viewed my project on W&B's web dashboard.

Comment: Possibly, I have never tried with a Kaggle notebook. Did you authenticate your account? When you first init WandB, it will ask you for an API key- I assume you completed this step.

Comment: It looks to be supported. See this link: https://www.kaggle.com/code/ayuraj/experiment-tracking-with-weights-and-biases

Comment: I got it to work by removing the dropout layers (probably not required for a fix) and, more important, adding an embedding layer. In my Notebook, save_model is not part of `wandb.keras` while the WandBModelCheckpoint callback passes an invalid `options` parameter. I can still use this to explore WandB for NLP.